# How can I create big empty white box and write some text in the middle of it?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int x, y;
        private int gap = 0;
        private int startingY = 150;
        private GroupBox lastGB = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
            gb.Location = new Point(100, (lastGB == null ? startingY : lastGB.Bounds.Bottom));
            gb.Size = new Size(1220, 400);
            gb.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            gb.Text = "";
            gb.Font = new Font("Colonna MT", 12);
            this.Controls.Add(gb);
        }
```

It's creating a small line on the top of the groupbox and I don't want this line to show.
And I want to write some text on it in the middle of it.

How can I make it just complete white ? And how to write some text in the middle on the groupbox ?

The main idea is to create over the form a white sheet or box with text inside that's it.

Comment: For controls that should just display text use a Label ! -  A Groupbox is meant to work as a container for other controls. Its Text is meant as a header for those other controls e.g. Radioboxes - Often an interesting and flexible option is to use a control's Paint event to e.Graphics.DrawString(...) text over a control with many options wrt varying colors, fornts etc..

Comment: You're using the wrong control.  GroupBox is for grouping other controls together.  You need a TextBox, or similar control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your intention is to put subsequent boxes just below the last box.  As mentioned, a `Label` would probably be best.  I'd also move that code to a method you can call over and over to keep from repeating code elsewhere. You could pass a message to display in the Label.  Also, don't forget to update the reference to the "last box" when ever you create a new one:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private int x, y;
    private int gap = 0;
    private int startingY = 150;
    private Label lastLbl = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddLabel("Hello World");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddLabel(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    private void AddLabel(String msg)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Location = new Point(100, (lastLbl == null ? startingY : lastLbl.Bounds.Bottom));
        lbl.Size = new Size(1220, 400);
        lbl.BackColor = Color.White;
        lbl.Text = msg;
        lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        lbl.Font = new Font("Colonna MT", 12);
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
        lastLbl = lbl;
    }
}
```